# Is there a cleaner way to return a data point than this: SchIndxRead %>% select(,.DormList) %>% filter(SchIndxRead$.College.Lookup=="MIAD")?

Tags: r, dataframe, select, filter, subset

I'd like to be able to select out data from my data.frame simply and elegantly, but I'm new to R.

This worked:

```
SchIndxRead %>% select(,.DormList) %>% filter(SchIndxRead$.College.Lookup=="MIAD")
```

I tried using this:

```
SchIndxRead[SchIndxRead$.College.Lookup=='MIAD',".DormList"]
```

And expected just "Two50Two"

but got this result:

```
> [1] "Two50Two" NA         NA         NA         NA        
> [6] NA         NA         NA         NA         NA        
>  [11] NA         NA         NA         NA         NA        
>  [16] NA         NA         NA         NA         NA        
>  [21] NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
```

Comment: Without the data, we can't be sure what's going on, but `SchIndxRead %>% select(.DormList) %>% filter(.College.Lookup=="MIAD")` is about as elegant as it gets in the tidy framework, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column `.College.Lookup` probably has `NA` values, such that the expression `SchIndxRead$.College.Lookup=="MIAD"` returns `TRUE`'s and `FALSE`'s, but also `NA`'s.

When you try to subset a variable with a vector that contains `NA`'s, the result will also have `NA`'s:

```
set.seed(10)
df = tibble(a = 1:10, b = sample(c(0, 1, NA), 10, TRUE))

> df
# A tibble: 10 × 2
       a     b
   <int> <dbl>
 1     1    NA
 2     2     0
 3     3     1
 4     4    NA
 5     5     1
 6     6    NA
 7     7    NA
 8     8    NA
 9     9    NA
10    10    NA

> df$b == 1
 [1]    NA FALSE  TRUE    NA  TRUE    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA

> df[df$b == 1, "a"]
# A tibble: 9 × 1
      a
  <int>
1    NA
2     3
3    NA
4     5
5    NA
6    NA
7    NA
8    NA
9    NA
```

That's why there were `NA`'s in your second attempt.

But `dplyr::filter` "ignores" `NA`'s, that is, it filters out rows where the condition returns `FALSE` **or** `NA`. That's why there weren't `NA`'s in your first attempt.

#### Two hints to improve your code:

1. It would've been better to change the order of `select` and `filter`:

```
SchIndxRead %>% filter(.College.Lookup == "MIAD") %>% select(.DormList)
```

This way you don't have to add the `SchIndxRead$` later.

2. You might prefer using `pull()`:

```
SchIndxRead %>% filter(.College.Lookup == "MIAD") %>% pull(.DormList)
```

Comment: Ricardo--Do you know how I can find volunteers or workers for a voting project? (to increase votership in college students). I have the data bbut I don't have the R Shiny skills.

Comment: @Judy I might be able to help! Can you tell me more about the project? This comment section isn't the best place for this though, but you can email me at ricardo.semiao@outlook.com